# control conditional Openmp in #define macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to use a `#define` flag to control using openmp or not.  Since `#pragma` can't not be inside a `#define`, so I tried

```
#define USE_OPENMP  // Toggle this on/off

#ifdef USE_OPENMP
    #define OMP_FOR(n)   __pragma("omp parallel for if(n>10)") 
#else
    #define OMP_FOR(n)   // do nothing        
#endif
```

then in my code I can:

```
int size_of_the_loop = 11;
OMP_FOR(size_of_the_loop) // activate openmp if(n>10)
for(){
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm not familiar with the `#define` related stuff, and wondering if it's possible achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Microsoft compiler will define the [`_OPENMP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) macro when the [`/openmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=vs-2019) compiler option is set. For your purpose you can use it in this form:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>     // This line won't add the library if you don't compile with -fopenmp option.
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
         // For Microsoft compiler
         #define OMP_FOR(n) __pragma(omp parallel for if(n>10)) 
    #else  // assuming "__GNUC__" is defined
         // For GCC compiler
         #define OMP_FOR(n) _Pragma("omp parallel for if(n>10)")
    #endif
#else
    #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
    #define OMP_FOR(n)
#endif
```

Now you can use `OMP_FOR(n)` like this:

```
int main() {
    int n=11;

    OMP_FOR(n)
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf("Thread %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
}
```

You have to compile the code with the following command:

```
cl /fopenmp file.c
```

or, if you're using GCC,

```
gcc -fopenmp file.c -o exe
```

Output for `n>10`:

```
Thread 2
Thread 0
Thread 1
Thread 3
```

Output for `n<10`:

```
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
```

Comment: is there anything special about the _OPENMP keyword? Or it is just conventional ?

Comment: @User800222 I don't know if it is the most conventional way, but its use is quite widespread. I've sarched the official manual and I haven't found anything about USE_OPENMP. 

You can find more information about how to use _OPENMP in the chapter 2.2 (page 40) of the official manual (https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf).

Comment: @User800222 Yes.

Comment: I added links to the Microsoft documentation and directives/keywords since OP tagged the question with `visual-studio`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the edit.  BTW, I've enable the openmp option in Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support -> Yes.  But i've tested the code above in VS 2015 & 2019 and both didn't work.  Printf show 'thread 0' only, any idea?

Comment: Through visual studio intellisense `_OPENMP` & `_MSC_VER` are both indeed triggered, but when I didn't use the marco but `#pragma omp parallel for` directly, it uses openmp.  Does it mean the `#define`  for `OMP_FOR` is incorrect?

Comment: I figured it out, it was the -> "  "  sign that make it didn't work, simply use `OMP_FOR(n) __pragma(omp parallel for if(n>10))`.  This will work on at least VS 2019 & 2015. (P.S. the solution was created by VS 2019)

Comment: @PabloCordero Do you know why when I compiled the code with g++ -fopenmp, it gave me the error of `Utils.h: In member function 'void Utils::conv2_v_sobel(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, const std::vector<kernel_type>&)':Utils.h:333:22: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
   OMP_FOR(rows * cols) //`  I tested it out that __GNUC__ was triggered.

Comment: @User800222 I would have to see the code. Looks like you can't use `OMP_FOR(rows * cols)`. Try using it like this:

`int n = rows*cols;
OMP_FOR(n);`

Comment: @PabloCordero Thank you for the help. And yes, it seems like `OMP_FOR(rows*cols)` works under microsoft's compiler, but doesn't work with gcc compiler.

Comment: In this code the pragma for non-VS compilers is given as a string `"omp parallel for if(n>10)"`, why would `n` inside a string be substituted by the argument of the macro?

Answer (score 6):

OpenMP compilers have to define `_OPENMP` per the OpenMP specification, as indicated by one of the comments.

Since OpenMP directives are based on pragmas, the compiler should ignore the OpenMP directives if it does not support OpenMP or if OpenMP is not enabled through the compiler switches.  So, unless you are relying on the OpenMP runtime API calls, there's usually no need for using `_OPENMP` in most codes.

EDIT: The OpenMP Architecture Review Board publishes a stub library at https://github.com/OpenMP/sources as source code.  This stub library can be used to supply the OpenMP API runtime library symbols and get "no op" stubs that correctly implement semantics for single-threaded execution.